# Importing fractional seconds from Excel to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an Excel 2013 workbook (XLSX) that contains dates with fractional seconds. I am trying to import this into SQL Server 2012, but it always seems to lose the fractional seconds.

Here is the excel sheet showing fractional seconds:

[image: 2014-10-01 02:16:05.25 PM]

To get this to display in Excel, I am using a custom format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.00 AM/PM. When converted to general, it displays the serial date 41913.5945052431.

When I create a Excel Source in SSIS (SQL Server Data Tools 2012), I get the following when I click the Preview button:

[image: SSIS Preview - 10/1/2014 2:16:05 PM]

The seconds round to the nearest whole second, instead of the fractional seconds. If I export from Excel to a CSV, I can import the CSV fine. Here is an image of the CSV:

[image: 1,2014-10-01 02:16:05.25 PM]

How can I get the Excel Source in SSIS to support fractional seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using  DT_DBTIMESTAMP data type.

OR

You can use script component as below.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(Dts.Variables["DateTimeString"].Value.ToString());
Dts.Variables["DateTimeString"].Value = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: This worked. I originally tried a Data Conversion task, but that didn't work. I used the following conversions to convert the incoming DateTime to a string and to a DBTIMESTAMP, which both include the fractional seconds. OutDateTime is a string, while OutTimestamp is a Timestamp. DateandTime is the input of type DT_DATE.  

`Row.OutDateTime = Row.DateandTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");  
Row.OutTimestamp = Row.DateandTime;`